# How to use ${tool 'MSBUILD'} in Powershell script from Jenkins?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, msbuild

I have a below batch command which is successfully executing in Jenkins pipeline script.

```bash
bat "\"${tool 'MSBuild 16'}\\msbuild\" /p:Configuration=\"${params.Configuration}\" /p:Platform=\"Any CPU\""
```

`${tool 'MSBuild 16'}` is not getting resolved to the path in Powershell script.

In below Powershell script, I want to replace `msbuild` with the path configured in Global Tool Configuration in Jenkins.

```ps
task Compile -depends Clean, DotNetCliVersion, Restore, AssemblyInfo {
    
     exec { msbuild /t:clean /v:q /nologo /p:Configuration=$configuration $product.sln }
     exec { msbuild /t:build /v:q /nologo /p:Configuration=$configuration $product.sln }
}
```

Comment: Try `${tool name: 'MSBuild 16', type: 'msbuild'}` and see if it works.

Comment: I am getting blank path with the above script.